# Ask random questions with no repeats

Tags: android

I want to create a quiz app where for example I have 3 questions. I want to ask them in random sequence and end the game once all questions have been answered but right now I can't it to do that. It is displaying random questions but it repeats currently. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here's my code:

```
package com.app.twelveimams;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Random;

public class Quiz extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button btn_one, btn_two, btn_three, btn_four;
    TextView tv_question;

    private Questions question = new Questions();

    private String answer;
    private int questionLength = question.questions.length;

    Random random;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.quiz);

        random = new Random();



        btn_one = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_one);
        btn_one.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_two = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_two);
        btn_two.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_three = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_three);
        btn_three.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_four = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_four);
        btn_four.setOnClickListener(this);

        tv_question = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_question);

        NextQuestion(random.nextInt(questionLength));
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.btn_one:
                if(btn_one.getText() == answer){
                    Toast.makeText(Quiz.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    NextQuestion(random.nextInt(questionLength));
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(Quiz.this, "Incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    NextQuestion(random.nextInt(questionLength));
                }

                break;

            case R.id.btn_two:
                if(btn_two.getText() == answer){
                    Toast.makeText(Quiz.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    NextQuestion(random.nextInt(questionLength));
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(Quiz.this, "Incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    NextQuestion(random.nextInt(questionLength));
                }

                break;

            case R.id.btn_three:
                if(btn_three.getText() == answer){
                    Toast.makeText(Quiz.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    NextQuestion(random.nextInt(questionLength));
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(Quiz.this, "Incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    NextQuestion(random.nextInt(questionLength));
                }

                break;

            case R.id.btn_four:
                if(btn_four.getText() == answer){
                    Toast.makeText(Quiz.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    NextQuestion(random.nextInt(questionLength));
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(Quiz.this, "Incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    NextQuestion(random.nextInt(questionLength));
                }

                break;
        }
    }

    private void GameOver(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Quiz.this);
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Game Over")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("New Game", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });
        alertDialogBuilder.show();

    }

    private void NextQuestion(int num){
        tv_question.setText(question.getQuestion(num));
        btn_one.setText(question.getchoice1(num));
        btn_two.setText(question.getchoice2(num));
        btn_three.setText(question.getchoice3(num));
        btn_four.setText(question.getchoice4(num));

        answer = question.getCorrectAnswer(num);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: strings aren't compared using ==

Comment: Rather than use a random generator, store a list of shuffled numbers, then remove them as you ask that question for that number

Comment: Can you give a sample code on how to do it?

Comment: Make `question.questions` an Arraylist rather than an array, and you're already halfway there. When you get the next question, just remove it from your list until there are no questions left. Feel free to [edit] your question to show your attempts at this

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Collections.shuffle(List<?> list)` to randamize the Question list.

```
package com.kundan.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Question {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> questionList = new ArrayList<String>();
        questionList.addAll(Arrays.asList("Question 1", "Question 2", "Question 3", "Question 4", "Question 5"));
        System.out.println(questionList);
        Collections.shuffle(questionList);
        System.out.println(questionList);
    }
}
```

Refer to the link below.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)